# How do I determine whether the columns of the matrix can be a basis for R^5?

Tags: linear-algebra

A = 
[ 1 2 3 4 5 ] (column 1), [ 0 0 0 0 0 ](column 2), [ 2 3 4 5 1 ](column 3), [ 7 12 17 22 17 ](column 4)

Determine whether the columns of A can be a basis for R^5 without using rref(A)? Explain.

My answer is, since there is a zero column, the columns of A are linearly dependent. Therefore it can't be a basis for R^5.

Is my answer correct?

Thank you

Comment: Your answer is great.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that if the zero vector is in a set, it cannot be a basis.  One property of a basis is the only way to express the zero vector is with a zero multiple of all the vectors in the set, and you can multiply the zero vector by something else and everything else by zero to express the zero vector.  There is another gimme here-you need five vectors to be a basis of $\Bbb R^5$ and only have four.  But it is reasonable to stop when you have the answer.

Comment: So is my answer correct and sufficient enough? Thank you

Comment: @FomoLoco:  yes it is.  I was just pointing out another way that the set failed to be a basis.  If we replace column 2 by [1 0 0 0 0]$ your explanation would not work any more but it still wouldn't be a basis.